# How to access TLS Secret via env variables in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a TLS Secret. And it looks like the following one...

```yaml
apiVersion: v1 
kind: Secret 
metadata:
  name: tls-ingress-secret 
  namespace: ingress-namespace 
type: kubernetes.io/tls 
data:
  tls.key: | 
    -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
    MIIEvwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKkwggSlAgEAAoIBAQCtwUrZ6zS+GdAw
    ldIUxIXpnajvAZun1mf8DD0nWJRBonzbBIZhLyHqQyPvz4B+ZfZ/ql/vucpLEPnq
    V3HqJraydt7kw/MBCS6a8GRObFx/faIWolbF5FjVgJexAxydeE35A7+hJUdElA7e
    jOVPzafz53oJvyCdtdRTVwbH6EA+aJGZ0eTmzRobLVdqmqCejN4soDeRZQcMXYrG
    uW+rTy3dyRCbMGV33GzYYJk2qBNFz+DqZbp1TyFcOQKBgQDW3IvXES4hfgtmj8NK
    0BKdX7gUyANdZooJ1tXoMjVmcFbdvoUprED3hpiI1WTYiZ3dqKD7QrHGsBW/yHZB
    UfFFxSj+vKotgxBhe06o2SDkXCnWfuQSJDZEgL/TuI9Qb/w1QeDxTZG4KCPiBrPD
    MiXRtvV7qdyWoPjUolWfWyef4K5NVo34TF4DHseY1QMoI8dTmB0nnZiDfZA6B+t0
    jgrnP8RpqaAOH8UjRwC+QMCfuq0SejUWocSobc/7K+7HJlMRwi6FuPXb7omyut+5
    34pCkfAj8Lwtleweh/PbSDnX9g==
    -----END PRIVATE KEY-----

  tls.crt: | 
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    MIIEDDCCAvSgAwIBAgIUDr8pM7eB+UPyMD0sY0yR5XmWrVQwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL
    BQAwgY8xCzAJBgNVBAYTAlJVMQ8wDQYDVQQIDAZSdXNzaWExDzANBgNVBAcMBk1v
    c2NvdzEmMCQGA1UECgwdS2lyaWxsIEtsaW11c2hpbnMgQ29ycG9yYXRpb24xHDAa
    BgNVBAsME09yZ2FuaXphdGlvbmFsIFVuaXQxGDAWBgNVBAMMD3d3dy5zdG9yZXJ1
    LmNvbTAeFw0yMjA3MjgxMTAyMThaFw0yMzA1MjQxMTAyMThaMIGPMQswCQYDVQQG
    PkBW2sS7dMxNLLeHyZ3st1SJfmWZhya1LsPvo1ilU3+d8rD5JjlC/cQ7EAF9DDXR
    i3/9zNzx3R6MMgNqkzQ89dDjHH+FZ2R0VkBKp35MYVg=
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

So the question is "is it possible to retrieve it as an env vars like: "tls.cert" and "tls.key", so I would be able to access it in my application...

What I want to receive from that is...

```golang
SSlCertFile := os.Getenv("tls.cert") // cert file with payload. 
SslCertKey := os.Getenv("tls.key") // cert file key.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox
spec:
  containers:
  - name: busybox
    image: busybox
    commands: ["ash","-c","sleep 3600"]
    envFrom:
    - secretRef:
        name: tls-ingress-secret
```

After you create the pod, try `kubectl exec -it busybox -- env`